# Python, random sample from a vector's non-zero indices

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, random

I have a 1-d vector called visited. I want to find randomly sample k indices of its zero position.

This is what I do now:

```
random.sample(np.where( visited == 0)[0]) , k)
```

Is there a better way of doing it?

Thanks

Comment: don't you mean `!=0`?

Comment: sorry, i wrote the wrong code, your answer works for nonzero, how to make it work for zeros?  Thanks. Because I know the visited is binary,  I may just do ( 1- visited).nonzero() ??? any better idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you're doing it is sound. However, you could use the more intuitive `nonzero` function:

```
random.sample(visited.nonzero(), k)
```

EDIT:

As to the second question in you comment, you can inverse the "zeroness" of you array: `visited==0`. You get:

```
random.sample((visited==0).nonzero(), k)
```